# Error getting when trying assign linq data into DTO class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to assign Linq data into my DTO class, but this Linq query getting mt this error.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I removed int convertion to avoid the error, then I got this error

**the type of one of the expressions in join clause is incorrect. type inference failed in the call to join**

My code as follows,

```
public class TextDto
{
    public string AddedData { get; set; }
    public string AddedTime { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Messsage { get; set; }
}
```

linq code,

```
var allText = from nm in context.NotificationMessages
join u in context.Users on new {
    Sender = (int) nm.Sender
}
equals new {
    Sender = u.UserId
}
select new {
    nm.Id,
    nm.AddedTime,
    nm.Lobby.Branch.BranchName,
    u.FirstName,
    u.LastName,
    nm.Message
};

var allTextList = allText.Select(data = >new TextOnDemandDto {

    AddedTime = data.AddedTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    Messsage = data.Message,
    Name = data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName

}).ToList();
```

This sql, which I converted into linq

```
SELECT nm.id,
       nm.addedtime,
       b.branchname,
       u.firstname,
       u.lastname,
       nm.message
FROM   notificationmessage nm
       INNER JOIN lobby l
               ON l.lobbyid = nm.fklobbyid
       INNER JOIN branch b
               ON b.branchid = l.fkbranchid
       INNER JOIN [user] u
               ON nm.sender = u.userid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your query to this:

```
var allText = (from nm in context.NotificationMessages
join u in context.Users 
on nm.Sender equals  u.UserId into ug
 from u in ug.DefaultIfEmpty()
join l in context.Lobbys 
 on    nm.fklobbyid eguals  l.lobbyid into lg
 from l in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join b in  context.Branches 
  on l.fkbranchid  equals b.branchid into bg
 from b in bg.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
    nm.Id,
    nm.AddedTime,
    b.BranchName,
    u.FirstName,
    u.LastName,
    nm.Message
}).ToList();
```

Update:

To get records with FKNotificationMessageTypeId = 3 insert where clause between "from b.." and "select":

```
... from b ...
where nm.FKNotificationMessageTypeId == 3
select new ....
```

Comment: the range variable nm conflicts with a previous declaration of nm

Comment: Could you show your NotificationMessage class pls

Comment: I made some changes to query

Comment: @sergy thanks sir, in `notifcationMessage` class u can see column have `FKNotificationMessageTypeId` I need to get `FKNotificationMessageTypeId = 3` data , how can I update this

Comment: If you need  FKNotificationMessageTypeId name I need  NotificationMessageType class correct name and primary key